# Broken page margins with boiboites package in Latex

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking

I'm  trying to write a mathematical proof with a `newboxedtheorem` command using `boiboites` package, but once the core is too long, I see no broken page, so a large part of my proof is missed in the output file, I will be very thankful if you could help me.

Here is my declaration:

```
\newenvironment{quotationb}
{\begin{leftbar}\begin{quotation}}
{\end{quotation}\end{leftbar}}
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=black, background=white, titlebackground=white, titleboxcolor = black,
size = 0.9\textwidth]{dem}{Démonstration}{compteurTH}
\renewcommand{\thecompteurTH}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{compteurTH}}
\newcommand{\norme}[1]{\left\Vert\par\nobreak\@afterheading #1\right\Vert}
```

and my proof:

```
\begin{dem}
Soit 
\begin{align}
Y_{t}&:=\mathbb{E}\lbrace\xi +\int^{T}_{t} f(s)ds\vert\mathcal{F}_{t}\rbrace,
\end{align}
D'après le théorème de représentation de Martingale il existe un processus stochastique adapté $Z \in \mathit{L}^{2}_{T} $ tel que :
\begin{align}
Y_{0}&:=\mathbb{E}\lbrace\xi +\int^{T}_{0} f(s)ds\vert\mathcal{F}_{t}\rbrace - \int_{0}^{T} Z_{s}dw_{s},
\end{align}
D'où le couple $(Y,Z)$ définit en (7) et (8) est une solution de (6), grâce a l'intégrabilité de $\xi$ on a  :
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\lbrace\xi +\int^{T}_{0} f(s)ds\vert\mathcal{F}_{T}\rbrace = \xi +  \int^{T}_{0} f(s)ds = T(0) + \int^{T}_{0} Z_{s}dW_{s},
\end{align}
Soit 
\begin{align}
 \int^{T}_{t} Z_{s}dW_{s}&=  \xi +\int^{T}_{0} f(s)ds - \mathbb{E}\lbrace\xi +\int^{T}_{0} f(s)ds\vert\mathcal{F}_{T}\rbrace,
\end{align}
Finalement on remplace par (7) dans (10) on retrouve le résultat, donc $(Y,Z)$ est la solution cherchée. \qedhere  
\end{dem}
\begin{prop}
Soit $\xi \in \mathit{L}^{2}_{T}$ la condition terminale, $f: \Omega\times[0,T]\mathbb{R}^{n\times d} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ le générateur $\mathcal{P}\bigotimes\mathcal{B}^{n\times d}$-mesurable, de telle sorte que $f(.,0)\in\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}$ Lipschitzienne par rapport a la deuxième variable, i.e:
$\exists C>0$ tel que :
\begin{align}
\vert f(t,z_{1})-f(t,z_{2})\vert \leq C\vert z_{1}-z_{2}\vert, \forall z_{1},z_{2}\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n},
\end{align}
Alors il existe un unique couple $(Y,Z)\in \mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\times\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$ solution de l'équation suivante :
\begin{align}
Y_{t}&=\xi +\int^{T}_{t} f(s,Z_{s})ds - \int^{T}_{t} Z_{s}dW_{s},
\end{align}
\end{prop}
\begin{dem}
\textbf{L'unicité :}\\ 
Soit $(Y,Z)$ et $(\tilde{Y},\tilde{Z})$ deux solutions de (12).D'après la formule d'Itô appliquée à $\vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y_{s}}\vert^{2}$.\newline
En fait, la dynamique de $\vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y_{s}}\vert^{2}$ est comme suit : 
\begin{align}
d \vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y_{s}}\vert^{2} = \lbrace f(t,Z_{t})-f(t,\tilde{Z}_{t})\rbrace dt + \lbrace Z - \tilde{Z}_{t}\rbrace dW_{t},
\end{align}
Soit \begin{align*}
\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y_{t}}\vert^{2}-\vert Y_{0}-\tilde{Y_{0}}\vert^{2} =& 2\int_{0}^{t} (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y_{s}},f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s}))ds \\&+ 2\int_{0}^{t} (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y_{s}},Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s})dW_{s} + \int_{0}^{t} \vert Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds,
\end{align*}
De la même façon
  \begin{align*}
 \vert Y_{T}-\tilde{Y}_{T}\vert^{2}- \vert Y_{0}-\tilde{Y_{0}}\vert^{2} = - \vert Y_{0}-\tilde{Y_{0}}\vert^{2} &= 2\int_{0}^{T} (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s},f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s}))ds\\ &+ 2\int_{0}^{T} ( Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s},Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s})dW_{s} + \int_{0}^{T} \vert Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds ,
\end{align*}
D'où 
\begin{align*}
 \vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2} + \int_{t}^{T} \vert\bar{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds &= -2\int_{t}^{T}  (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s},f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s}))ds  \\ &- 2\int_{0}^{T} (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}, Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s})dW_{s},
\end{align*}
On exploite le faite que $f$ est Lipschitzienne on a la majoration suivante : 
\begin{align*}
\left(  Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s},f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s})\right) &=-2\left( \sqrt{2}c (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}),\dfrac{f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s})}{\sqrt{2}c}\right) \\
&=2c^{2}\vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}\vert^{2} + \dfrac{\vert f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s})\vert^{2}}{2c^{2}}\\ & - \vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s} + f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s}) \vert^{2} \\
& \leq 2c^{2}\vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}\vert^{2} + \dfrac{\vert f(s,Z_{s})-f(s,\tilde{Z}_{s})\vert^{2}}{2c^{2}}\\ 
& 2c^{2}\vert Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}\vert^{2} + \dfrac{C \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}}{2},
\end{align*}
On regroupant l'inégalité et l'égalité précédentes on a :\newpage
\begin{align*}
\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2} + \int_{t}^{T} \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds &\leq \int_{t}^{T} \lbrace 2c^{2}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}\rbrace ds\\ &- 2\int_{0}^{T} (Y_{s}-\tilde{Y}_{s}, Z_{s} - \tilde{Z}_{s})dW_{s},
\end{align*}
On faisant intervenir l'espérance, d'intégrale stochastique s'annule puisque $(Y,Z)\in \mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\times\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$, Soit alors 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2} + \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T} \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds &\leq 2c^{2}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}  \vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2}ds + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2} ds,
\end{align} 
il s'en suit que 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2} \leq -\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T} \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds \\&+ 2c^{2}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2}ds,
\end{align}
D'après le lemme de Gronwall appliquée à (15): 
\begin{align*}
0\leq\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2}\leq-\frac{1}{2}e^{2c^{2}(T-t)}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T} \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds\leq 0,
\end{align*}
d'où 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{t}-\tilde{Y}_{t}\vert^{2}=\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T} \vert Z_{s}-\tilde{Z}_{s}\vert^{2}ds = 0,
\end{align}
ce qui prouve l'unicité du couple solution.\\
 \textbf{L'existence:} \\
Soit $(Y_{0}(t),Z_{0}(t))\equiv (0,0),\lbrace(Y_{n}(t),Z_{n}(t)),0\leq t\leq T\rbrace_{n\geq}$ une suite de $\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{d})\times\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$, solution par l'équation stochastique rétrograde suivante :
\begin{align}
Y_{n}(t)= \xi + \int_{t}^{T}f(s,Z_{n-1}(s))ds - \int_{t}^{T}Z_{n}(s)dW_{s},
\end{align}
La suite est bien définit grâce au lemme 1.\newline
En suivant la même démarche utilisé dans (14) pour $\vert Y_{n+1}(s)-Y_{n}(s)\vert^{2}$ pour $s=t$, $s=T$ , et en utilisant le fait que $f$ est Lipschitzienne, on trouve l'inégalité suivante :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{n+1}(t)-Y_{n}(t)\vert^{2} + \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{n+1}(s)-Z_{n}(s)\vert^{2}ds&\leq 2c^{2} \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Y_{n+1}(s)-Y_{n}(s)\vert^{2}ds\\
 &+ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{n}(s)-Z_{n-1}(s)\vert^{2}ds,
\end{align*}
ce qui est équivalent à :
\begin{align*}
-  \dfrac{d}{dt}\left( e^{2c^{2}t} \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Y_{n+1}(s)-Y_{n}(s)\vert^{2}ds\right)e^{-2c^{2}t}  + \mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{n+1}(s)-Z_{n}(s)\vert^{2}ds\leq
  \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{n}(s)-Z_{n-1}(s)\vert^{2}ds,
\end{align*} 
Soit $u_{n}(t):=\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Y_{n}(s)-Y_{n-1}(s)\vert^{2}ds$ and $v_{n}(t):=\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{n}(s)-Z_{n-1}(s)\vert^{2}ds$,
Alors on a :
\begin{align}
-\dfrac{d}{dt}(u_{n+1}(t)e^{2c^{2}t})+e^{2c^{2}t}v_{n+1}(t)\leq \frac{1}{2}e^{2c^{2}t}v_{n}(t),
\end{align}
Intégrons cette formule entre $t$ et $T$, sachant que $u_{n}(T)=0$  : 
\begin{align*}
u_{n+1}(t)e^{2c^{2}t}+\int^{T}_{t} e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n+1}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{2}\int^{T}_{t}e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n}(s)ds,
\end{align*}
Soit : 
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}(t)+\int^{T}_{t} e^{2c^{2}(s-t)}v_{n+1}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{2}\int^{T}_{t}e^{2c^{2}(s-t)}v_{n}(s)ds,
\end{align}
Soit $\bar{c}:=\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}\vert Z_{1}(s)\vert^{2}ds = sup_{0\leq t\leq T}v_{1}(t)$,
alors 
\begin{align*}
\int^{T}_{0} e^{2c^{2}t}v_{1}(t)dt =\int^{T}_{0}e^{2c^{2}t}\mathbb{E}\int_{t}^{T}\vert Z_{1}(s)\vert^{2}dsdt \leq \int^{T}_{0}e^{2c^{2}T}\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}\vert Z_{1}(s)\vert^{2}dsdt = \bar{c}e^{2c^{2}T},
\end{align*}
Comme $(u_{n})_{n\geq 0}$,$(v_{n})_{n\geq 0}$ sont à terme positif, alors :
\begin{align*}
\int^{T}_{t} e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n+1}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{2}\int^{T}_{t}e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n}(s)ds,
\end{align*}
d'où 
\begin{align*}
\int^{T}_{t} e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n+1}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{2}\int^{T}_{t}e^{2c^{2}s}v_{n}(s)ds\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}\bar{c}e^{2c^{2}T},
\end{align*}
En particulier, d'après (19) on a :
 \begin{align}
u_{n+1}(0)\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}\bar{c}e^{2c^{2}T},
\end{align}
Or, $\dfrac{d}{dt}u_{n+1}(t)=-\mathbb{E}\vert Y_{n+1}(t)-Y_{n}(t)\vert^{2}\leq 0 $ alors on a d'après la formule (18): 
\begin{align}
v_{n+1}(0)\leq \frac{1}{2}v_{n}(0) \leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}v_{1}(0)
\end{align}
Donc d'après (20) et (21), les suites $u_{n},$et,$v_{n}$ sont convergentes en d'autre terme :
$(Y_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in$et $ Z_{n}(t))_{n\geq 1}$ sont de Cauchy, de plus les espaces $\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$,et $\mathit{H}^{2}_{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n\times d})$ sont complets elles convergent pour tout $t\geq 0$, soit :
$$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} Y_{n}= Y, \qquad \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} Z_{n}= Z$$  
Donc par construction le couple $(Y,Z)$ est solution de (12).
\end{dem}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your post to combine your fragments into a complete minimal example we can compile to see the problem. Is this problem specific to LuaTeX? Did you mean the `boites` package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The package boiboites won't let you break boxes over multiple pages.

You should use xeboiboites instead, available here:

https://github.com/alexisflesch/xeboiboites